# links in repeat region

Tags: hyperlink

I am quite new to Dreamweaver and need some assistance. I have created a repeat region displaying names from a database. I would like to link each name to a separate Word document that can be downloaded in a web browser.

Answer (score 1):

Fetch the data and link like this:

```
while(info = fetch_frm_database( data )) 
 { 
 Print "<a href="info['siteurl'] . ">" .info['sitetitle'] . "</a><br>"; 
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I am lost. Please, could you give a little more explanation. Could you make reference to the repeat region that I created and the different word documents that I need to attach